# How to disable tier pricing for a special promotion?

Tags: magento-1.7, discount, tierprice

Is there a way we can disable tier prices for a weekend promotion? I need to offer 30% discount for the entire store, but tier prices make it so hard. Actually I'm removing tier prices by product each one. After the promotion I need to load each product and set the tier price again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved saving data and cleaning Tier Price table. After the promotion reload table data. It works.

Comment: Please remember to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: please accept this as answer for your question, so that future visitors will get benefited from your question